# Correct using of mobile viewport on different devices with small width

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have such css code for mobile devices:

```
@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 991px) {...}
```

and i have such html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1" id="viewportMt">

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    if(screen.width < 970) {
      var vp = document.getElementById('viewportMt');
      vp.setAttribute('content','width=640, initial-scale=1');
    }
  }
</script>
```

the main problem, is that when i firstly open my website: on most of devices i have to scale my browser view to fit it...

is it possible to fit device automatically? for example if device width is 340: i should scale it out a little bit (because website is to big for 340px (it;s min.640px))... If 900: then scale too...

even ipad (in portrait mode, because it's width is 768px).

is it possible to do?

plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5KhIlmtLkWhtROs7y188?p=preview

and demo:

[image]

why i have there scrollbar? i need somehow to zoom it out, so that i will not have any scrollbar there...
and my container should be 640px and no other values for mobile devices...

Comment: did you try adding a css of max width and height 100% ??

Comment: you are mixing two things in here. one is using css responsive `@media` queries and other, static viewport width to scale the website. what exactly are you trying to achieve in the final result? to have a responsive webpage with native device resolution or scale the whole page down depending on the device width?

Comment: @user151496 `scale the whole page down depending on the device width`, but with min-width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use for all my responsive web apps.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML5 zoom property as seen below. This will zoom the body to + or -. Any value can be used.

```
<body style="zoom:50%;">
```

Comment: but it's a little bit "hardcode"...
for iphone4 - it's good, but is bad for ipad ;)

Comment: If it worked for you already, please mark it answer coz it appears regularly in my personal profile page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 zoom:

```
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

See http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/zoom for supported browsers.

So then you can write a JS function to choose the correct amount of zoom.

Comment: but it's a little bit "hardcode"...
for iphone4 - it's good, but is bad for ipad ;)

Comment: How do you mean? You could write a JS function with a math formula to choose the correct amount of zoom I think.

Comment: It is not scaling it. You asked to zoom out the page at the landing

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Zoom:0.5;
```

Without using % value
Or set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1" />
```